# making a new column with last 10 digits of an other colulmn

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, substring

I used

```
UPDATE user SET phone_last_ten = SUBSTR(phone, -10)
```

to make

`phone_last_ten column`.

All went ok, but I got `0` zeros for `phone_last_ten` where `phone` was `< 10 chars/digits`  . any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Right](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-right-function.php) function

MySQL RIGHT() extracts a specified number of characters from the right side of a string.

```
UPDATE user SET phone_last_ten = RIGHT(phone, 10)
```

**Or**

```
UPDATE user SET phone_last_ten = RIGHT(CONVERT(Phone, CHAR(50)), 10)
```

## [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29850)

Comment: the columns are ints/bigints. I hope it wont matter?

Comment: @MasoodAhmad I think it will applicable for all , if not you can use convert..I have updated it in my answer. Mark useful if it's helped you

Answer (score 2):

Use [**RIGHT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_right) function instead of `SUBSTR` function

Try this:

```
UPDATE autumn4.application_user 
SET phone_last_ten = RIGHT(phone, 10);
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE autumn4.application_user 
SET phone_last_ten = RIGHT(CAST(phone AS CHAR(20)), 10);
```

Comment: the columns are ints/bigints. I hope it wont matter?

Comment: @MasoodAhmad It won't metter. If you still confused then cast that column into varchar. Check my updated answer